# Stray '\345' in program?

Tags: c

My code:

```
    const int timer = 8;
    const int dager = 5;
    const float måned = 4.33;
    const int uker = 52;

    printf("forste persons navn: ");
    scanf("%s", navn1);

    printf("Andre persons navn: ");
    scanf("%s", navn2);

    printf("timelonn til forste person: %i");
    scanf("%i", timelonn1);

    printf("antall uker ferie til forste person: %i");
    scanf("%i", ukeferie1);

    printf("timelonn til andre person: %i");
    scanf("%i", timelonn2);

    printf("antall uker ferie til andre person: %i");
    scanf("%i", ukeferie2);

    return 0;
}
```

Errors I am getting:

```
error: stray '\345' in program

error: expected "=", ',',', 'asm' or '_attribute_'before 'ned'

error: 'ned' undeclared (first use in this functon)
```

Comment: `måned` - has some weird character that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Keep non-ascii characters out of your variables names.  Just use A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and _ (underscore).

Comment: Aside: don't use `%i` as a `scanf` format spec unless the user is expected to enter octal or hexadecimal too. Use `%d` for a regular user. For example in your code an input of `012` will be decimal `10` not `12`. Also from the code fragment it isn't clear why you pass `timelonn1` to `scanf` and not `&timelonn1`, etc.

Comment: From *[Why are special characters not allowed in variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250231/why-are-special-characters-not-allowed-in-variable-names/24252465#24252465)*: *"More modern languages (Java, C#, Scala, ...., uh, even PARLANSE) grew up in an era of Unicode, and tend to allow most of Unicode in identifiers"*

Comment: The non-ASCII in one of the variable names suggests this is a blatant duplicate. Where is the canonical question?

Comment: The title of your question should tell us something about the question. "_error: stray '\345' in program_" might be a good title.  Omit the biographical information. You can add that to your profile page.

Comment: What compiler are you using? C 2018 6.4.2.1 and D.1 say that various universal characters should be allowed in identifiers, including hex 00E5 (octal 345). GCC, Clang, and MSVC all accept this.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: The C standard has allowed non-ASCII characters in identifiers since C 1999 at least.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, yet the OP's compiler does not, so it is rather academic what the standard allows perhaps.

Comment: @Clifford: It is not academic whether the solution is their compiler does not support it, they have had some problem in editing their source file and/or saving it in an appropriate format, or some other problem has occurred. We know the statement that “special characters” are not allowed in variable names is incorrect for C generally, and Stack Overflow is not for guessing at answers to questions. OP’s compiler ought to be determined, and the reason they got this error message ought to be determined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil My point was that the compiler the OP is using has rejected `å` in the source.  The reason for that may be use of an older compiler or explicit enforcement of an older standard, for any number of reasons error or intentional.  I am not saying it is not allowed by any standard, rather explaining why it is not allowed by this compiler.  It is the compiler that gets stuff done, not the standard.  A long time ago, I encountered this issue in gcc 2.95 using a copyright symbol in a comment.

Comment: ...While using a newer compiler/standard may be good advice, it is not an answer to this question.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil: I didn't claim it wasn't allowed (on contrary. It being allowed in other C-like languages suggests there is nothing inherently blocking it). I am only interested in the canonical question. This question was posted in 2022. It must have been asked many times over in the past 14 years.

Comment: Candidate canonical questions: *[ (and other Unicode characters) in identifiers not allowed by g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692067/)* (2012), *[What constitutes a "valid" C Identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319000/)* (2015), and *[Using emoji as identifier names in C++ in Visual Studio or GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130806/)* (2015). [More candidates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/12692067?sort=votes).

Comment: And *[Why don't these Unicode variable names work with -fextended- identifiers? «, » and ≠](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799078/why-dont-these-unicode-variable-names-work-with-fextended-identifiers-a)* (2015)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is here:

```
const int timer = 8;
const int dager = 5;
const float måned = 4.33; // This variable
const int uker = 52;
```

You are using characters not supported by the compiler (å).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc) seems to support that this is your issue. See the non-[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters%3E) character used in the source code that would not compile.

Answer (score -1):

The C programming language defines a [*basic source character set*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/charset) comprising a subset of 95 ASCII characters from which source code may be composed. The character `å` is not one of them; for good reason (historically); it is not available in all code pages (used for regionally defined 8-bit characters), and is not available on all regional keyboards.

Essentially your code must be composed from characters universally available regardless of regionalisation and character encoding.

`\345` is an octal (base 8) character code sequence used to represent characters. Here it is used in the error message because the character set used in presentation of error messages may (in a GUI IDE for example) may differ from that used in code presentation.  345<sub>8</sub> is 229 decimal or E5 hexadecimal.  In the Windows-1252 code page, that happens to be `å`, but is not universally true.

Comment: [Code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)? Aren't we long past them? It could be [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). It is allowed in variable names in [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), [Scala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scala_%28programming_language%29), [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29), etc.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, perhaps, but C is _that old_ that it _was_ a consideration when it was defined.  I mention it as a historical explanation for the restrictive subset.  Edited to make that more explicit.  Regional keyboards remains a valid consideration of course.